# Getting a float error when trying to access first value from a dictionary in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, lambda

I have a DataFrame where one column contains a dictionary. I am trying to return the first value from the dictionary by using apply and a lambda function but I keep getting an error related to floats. This is confusing because I have a dictionary not a float that I am trying to iterate through.

Error message example:
*'float' object has no attribute 'get'*

When I run the below code I get dict as the object type

```
type(all_addr['street address'][0])
```

But when I run this, I get the error about the float

```
all_addr['street address'].apply(lambda x: x.get('address_components'))
```

This is an example of a dictionary that is stored in the column in the DataFrame:

```
{'address_components': [{'long_name': '871',
   'short_name': '871',
   'types': ['street_number']},
  {'long_name': '8th Avenue', 'short_name': '8th Ave', 'types': ['route']},
  {'long_name': 'Manhattan',
   'short_name': 'Manhattan',
   'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_1']},
  {'long_name': 'New York',
   'short_name': 'New York',
   'types': ['locality', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'New York County',
   'short_name': 'New York County',
   'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'New York',
   'short_name': 'NY',
   'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']},
  {'long_name': 'United States',
   'short_name': 'US',
   'types': ['country', 'political']},
  {'long_name': '10019', 'short_name': '10019', 'types': ['postal_code']},
  {'long_name': '5761',
   'short_name': '5761',
   'types': ['postal_code_suffix']}],
 'formatted_address': '871 8th Ave, New York, NY 10019, USA',
 'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 40.7637343, 'lng': -73.985334},
  'location_type': 'ROOFTOP',
  'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.76508328029149,
    'lng': -73.9839850197085},
   'southwest': {'lat': 40.7623853197085, 'lng': -73.9866829802915}}},
 'place_id': 'ChIJtVPYoldYwokRyDoPj7jHHwk',
 'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'Q277+FV New York, NY, USA',
  'global_code': '87G8Q277+FV'},
 'types': ['street_address']}
```

Essentially I just want to get the address_components list out of this dictionary so I can then get to some of the data elements held inside that list. I have used similar functions with DataFrames and dictionaries before and have not run into this error.

I am running this in Google Colab and the dictionary data is coming from the Google Maps API.

Comment: Are all of the items in 'street address' dicts? Or are some floats?

Comment: One of the values in `all_addr['street address']` is a `float` so when you iterate through the column values you are essentially doing `.9.get()`

Comment: More likely, some of your values are "missing". Missing values in `pandas` are represented as `NaN` which is of type `float64`. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help to show the ouput for
`all_addr['street address'].apply(lambda x: type(x))`. Also, `.apply()` is pretty slow for just getting values out of a column so [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) may help in getting just extracting the address_components list for you.